# Could an AMPscript content block be affecting the format of the email in Gmail?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, content-builder, gmail

I have an email that uses a standard responsive Marketing Cloud template, which has an image block at the top, html content block in the middle (which is all AMPscript), followed by a social follow block, footer logo, and unsubscribe footer block.

When the email is received in Gmail the email splits after the AMPscript block. I understand Gmail does this for messages over 102kb, but I'm not sure why the social follow and unsubscribe blocks change format from centred to left aligned.

Could this be related to the AMPscript block at all? The reason I ask is when I test the email without that AMPscript block it formats correctly in Gmail.

I should also note the formatting is fine when sending to Outlook. Unfortunately, I don't have access to Litmus to check other email clients.

Looking for ideas to troubleshoot.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Likely not the AMPscript block itself but it could be something not closed inside the block that is causing this (since you took out the block and it looked fine).

Comment: Thank you Jackson. You were right!

Comment: Glad I could help @GregBeazley